# MATLAB : How to crop an object from a binary image by identifying some features?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, crop

I have an image like shown here: [image: Finger_vein]
My ultimate aim is to extract the vein pattern in the finger. So What I am trying to do is the extraction of the finger object alone. For that purpose, I tried an Otsu thresholding step first, then an erosion and dilation. Now using the binary image as a mask I multiplied element wise with original image to obtain the finger alone (not that accurate though). [image]

The code is as below:

```
I = imread('3.5.bmp');
[level] = graythresh(I);
BW = im2bw(I,level);
[BWm] = imerode(BW,strel('disk',10)); figure, imshow(BWm)
[BWmm] = imdilate(BWm,strel('disk',15)); figure, imshow(BWmm)
B = I.*uint8(BWmm); % BWmm is the mask
imshow(B)
```

Now I want to crop this finger part alone using the mask which I created before. How to achieve that?

For clarity I am uploading the image with the area to be cropped: [image] (And finally I don't want to do this manually or using imcrop() utility with pixel coordinates as input. I would like to get those pixel coordinate using some algorithms.)

Comment: Do you want to improve the segmentation of the image? Is that your question?

Comment: I want the output image as single finger object alone.

Comment: Could you add an image where you draw manually in red the area you would like to segment, please?

Comment: I have added the image as you told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the pixel coordinates from the mask `BWmm` and then use the coordinates with `imcrop`.

To find the extermal points of `BWmm` use

```
projX = any( BWmm, 1 ); % projection of mask along x direction
projY = any( BWmm, 2 ); % projection of mask along y direction
fx = find( projX, 1, 'first' ); % first column with non-zero val in mask
tx = find( projX, 1, 'last' );  % last column with non-zero val in mask
fy = find( projY, 1, 'first' ); % first row with non-zero val in mask
ty = find( projY, 1, 'last' );  % last row with non-zero val in mask
cropRect = [fx, fy, tx-fx+1, ty-fy+1];
cImg = imcrop( I, cropRect );
```

Comment: That seems to be great. Let me try this.

Comment: Works perfect. Just one more thing. Is the code written by me OK. Is there any better methods to achieve this?

Comment: @dexterdev it's hard to say from looking at just one example. But your code is simple and that is a great plus.