# Find coordinates from binary image and project them to original

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image which I have converted to a binary mask.
My regions of interest are those with 1 in the mask.

I want to find the coordinates of these regions,
and go to the original image (same dimensions) so I can crop the unprocessed part of the image.

Comment: do you want the RGB values of the pixels set to 1 in the binary mask? in what format/shape do you want your output? please try and define more precisely what you are after.

Comment: I just want to save the coordinates where there is 1 in my table. Then find the same ones in the original image and crop it.

Comment: Do you want a single image cropped (find bounding box and `imcrop`) to the limits of your binary one, or multiple extracted images for separate regions? (`regionprops`, bounding box, then `imcrop`).

Comment: @nkjt http://i.imgur.com/mKGirQ7.png I want to somwhow, get the position of everything that is white. Then using that information find the same position in the original image and crop it. But only for the original image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB : How to crop an object from a binary image by identifying some features?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263101/matlab-how-to-crop-an-object-from-a-binary-image-by-identifying-some-features)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27342437/1714410) to get a bounding box from your binary mask.
Once you have the bounding box (`rect` variable in the aforementioned answer) you can use [`imcrop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcrop.html) to crop the original image around it

```
cIm = imcrop( origImg, rect );
```

Comment: That was EXACTLY that i needed. All my upvotes. Was desperate.